# Writing to external storage?

Tags: java, android, file, android-external-storage

I have written codes from the tutorials of SLIDENERD to save info in different areas as internal cache,External cache,Private information and public information with the following codes.

```
EditText uname,pwd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    uname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
}

public void intCache(View view){
    File fileDir=getCacheDir();
   File myFile=new File(fileDir,"User_info_intCache.txt");
    write(myFile);
}

public void extCache(View view){
    File fileDir=getExternalCacheDir();
    File myFile=new File(fileDir,"User_info_extCache.txt");
    write(myFile);
}

public void pvtDir(View view){
    File fileDir=getExternalFilesDir("User_Info");
    File myFile=new File(fileDir,"User_info_pvtExt.txt");
    write(myFile);
}

public void pubDir(View view){
    File fileDir= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File myFile=new File(fileDir,"User_info_pubExt.txt");
    write(myFile);
}
private void write(File myFile){
    String unameS=uname.getText().toString();
    String pwdS=pwd.getText().toString();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=null;
    try {
        fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        try {
            fileOutputStream.write(unameS.getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.write(pwdS.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this,"data is written to "+myFile.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the files user_info_extCache.txt , User_info_pvtExt.txt. I know that internal cache location ( User_info_intCache.txt ) cant be seen.But i can't find the User_info_pubExt.txt file which must be stored in public directory Downloads.I cant see the file created by following code.

```
File fileDir= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File myFile=new File(fileDir,"User_info_pubExt.txt");
```

The toast shows that the file is created by above piece of code under /storage/emulated/0/Download/User_info_pubExt.txt .

I find somewhere that if phone is connected to pc,external storage cant be accessed.So i tried both by removing the mobile from pc.The toast says that file is created.But i cant find it under that folder.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.iamka.storage">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
</application>
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: You cant find it? Did you use a file explorer app on your device?

Answer (score 0):

Your toast claiming that data is written is on the wrong place. As the toast also displays when there is an exception.

Place the toast in the try block instead. Or yet better after the close() but only if you close().

And place other toasts in the catch blocks to inform the user with `e.getMessage()`.

As for the exception: all the paths exept the last one do not need any read/write permission at all. For the latter you need read/write permission.

But requesting them in manifest is not enough for Android 6+ as then you have to add some code to ask the user to confirm the requested permissions.

Google for runtime permissions.